# What is the security of using XMPP for VoIP?

Tags: security, xmpp, sip, voip

Let's say I use Jitsi to make VoIP conference calls using XMPP. What determines the security, is it a feature of the XMPP protocol itself or is it the account/server I am using (eg, www.jabber.org)? On the Jabber website they mention using SSL and TLS, would this be for VoIP?

What is the advantage of using ZRTP over just making a regular voice call through XMPP, assuming there is already some security with XMPP?

Is there a difference in using SIP vs. XMPP for voice calls, with or without ZRTP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMPP and SIP are known as "signalling protocols". They are designed to provide channels that allow two clients to communicate small packets of data with each other. SIP was designed primarily with just signalling as a goal, while XMPP was designed primarily with messaging and presence as a goal. Over time both have gradually extended into each others' realm though :)

However neither SIP nor XMPP technically carry the actual voice/video data. This is left up to other protocols, such as RTP, ZRTP, etc., which the clients use the signalling protocol to negotiate (e.g. they need to exchange IP addresses and port information, and keys for ZRTP).

This means that running your XMPP over SSL is essential for security, but it only protects the signalling part (the clients negotiating the media channel). The voice/video does not go over the XMPP channel, and must be separately protected, by using ZRTP.

Comment: SSL is not enough, since it does not guarantee end-to-end encryption, and even worse, relies or a form of (by definition untrustworthy) “authority”. (A logical fallacy.)
PGP/GPG’s way of building a *web of trust* would be the correct way of doing this.

Comment: SSL/TLS does not require you to use recognised CAs, it is possible (though in many cases impractical) to create your own, and offer equivalent security. There are end-to-end encryption mechanisms in the pipeline for XMPP, for when you must use untrusted services (sadly OTR, though popular, does not go far enough to be able to protect media signalling).